# Need CODE help with function to List ALL folders AND all files

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive

**EDIT:**
Have now attempted to run the Tedinoz code found in forums here and am able to get filenames but only from two folders within the main folder... The two folders it's NOT reading, have several child folders. IS there a known limit to the number of child folders that can be acquired from Google App Script??

I have a script from @mesgarpour that I'm running on Google Drive to list out all assets therein. I have modified slightly to gain recursion down to the lowest file levels. But, while it runs, it is only listing the folders and subfolders AND NOT the files inside them. I am pasting the code below and would appreciate any help. **AGAIN**: I am looking for the script to list **all files** along with the other data that I'm getting.

Have attached image shows the style of folder names as well as the fact that only folders are being shown by the script.

```
// TODO: Set folder ID
var folderId = 'My folder ID';
 
// Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listFolers(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listAll(){
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// =================
// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
    
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    // Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
      childFolder.getDescription(),
      childFolder.getSize()
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
        childFile.getDescription(),
        childFile.getSize()
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```

[image: the attached image shows the style of folder names as well as the fact that only folders are being shown by the script]

Comment: RELATED: [Google script listing folders, subfolders and files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696774/1330560)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of Drive files into a spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120867/get-a-list-of-drive-files-into-a-spreadsheet)

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz it does not go beyond listing the folders and even then doesn't list all of them. The code I posted goes a bit further. What I need is how to press the recursion further.

Comment: Um. The “related” script “will create a List with FolderName, FolderID, Filename and FileID of all Folders and Files included in a Google Drive Fiolder”. The “Does this answer?” includes a image that displays folder and sub-folders AND file names. Why debug _your_ script when there are tried-and-tested scripts that will do EXACTLY what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is not unfortunately, hence my tinkering. I'm using the script that you @Tedinoz provided in your response to me, unadulterated save for changing the folderID and it is only giving me the lowest folder level, but not files within the folders. I'd already searched for and found the script when the one I found initially didn't go far enough. Not sure why its not working, would love any ideas anyone has about solving it.

Comment: I've run your code (`listAll`) and the Tedinoz code (`ListNamedFilesandFolders`) and there is not the least doubt that they both work, and that they both "list" folders, sub-folders AND file names.  You say "it is only listing the folders and subfolders AND NOT the files inside them". Would you please edit your question to describe EXACTLY which function you are running AND include a screenshot of the first couple of rows and columns of your output.

Comment: have edited post as requested. i've wondered if its something to do with the naming conventions we use, but there are no errors being returned. but i'll reiterate that i am NOT getting filenames, the lowest levels i'm reaching are indeed folders.

Comment: Which function did you run to get that screenshot? And of the folders shown in that listing, which actually contain any files?

Comment: from running the function linked here (listFolders): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682295/google-script-listing-folders-subfolders-and-files/58696774#58696774. It gets me to the same point as the megaspour function. However the ListNamedFilesandFolders only returns top level folders. All the folders have MANY files.

Comment: OK, but let's talk about YOUR code for a moment. Your `listFolers` (note the spelling) does NOT list any files - it ONLY lists folders. The clue is in the function comment "Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet." SOOOO, you need to run YOUR `listAll`. The output shown in Column B will list sub-folders as well as FILES. Please give that a go. WARNING: If you have a LOT of files, then you might choose a "small" folder for testing.

Comment: I appreciate your continued if somewhat laden responses; I am not a coder as you seem to be. The script I originally posted specifically has listAll as a second main function ... so I'm perplexed. 

Further, I just rolled back and ran ListNamedFilesandFolders() and it's  returning FILES YES ! but only from two out four higher level folders out of several many, accounting for 13 files out of hundreds. I am truly at a loss. 
Editing my post with new question about scripts,
Will continue to press on this and report back on (hopefully) future success

Comment: Please don't add to/change your question; it is hard enough trying to trouble-shoot the code that we already have. Would you please delete the new edit - FYI, the answer is "no".

Comment: "it's returning FILES YES ! but only from two out four higher level folders out of several many, accounting for 13 files out of hundreds." Respectfully, if we're to help you, then you need to provide accurate and complete information. Remember, we don't know the structure of your folders and sub-folders, and we don't know file names, types or locations - we rely on you to tell us this information IN DETAIL.

Comment: "FILES YES ! but only from two out four higher level folders out of several". OK-let's tease this out. **FOLDERS**: Did the script display **ALL** of the folders/sub-folders that exist in/under `foldername` (line 9 of the script)?  If not, please edit your question to include a list of all the relevant folders/sub-folders in/below the `foldername` and highlight those folders/sub-folders that were **NOT** displayed by the script. I'm not worried about "files" at this stage, just folders. PS: this is going to take a very LONG time unless we can find a way to discuss off-line.

Comment: Tease out#2. **FILES**: Regarding the files that _were_ displayed, look at the folder locations of those files and establish whether there were files in those locations that were NOT displayed. If you find any location(s) where some files were listed and some files were NOT listed, then choose one location and please edit your question to include file details for that location, including every file name and its type and highlight the files that were **NOT** displayed by the script.

Comment: Script remains unchanged in my posting. As for the two folders where files were displayed, they do not contain subfolders AND all files contained therein were displayed. The two other folders (driving me to seek out a solution) are the ones that have many sub/child folders. It's very confusing to me because the script I posted above, will show all the folders and not the files - that's really where I need the focus. Appreciate your time and effort here, but may need to find an alternative.

Comment: You don't need an alternative. Just run your function `listAll()`. It will work.